# Skip jquery change event on initial page load

Tags: jquery

I have a change event that fires on initial page load because of dynamically constructed html and dom elements. I do not want it to fire on initial page load, only on subsequent changes done by users after page has loaded. Here's the change event:

```
$('select[data-name="ProductID"]').live('change', function () {
  ... do stuff
}
```

How can I stop this from firing during page load?

Comment: how about using a flag.?

Comment: Rajaprabhu, please be more specific. A flag is fine, but I don't know what event it would key off.

Comment: how about surround it in `$(document).ready(function(){/* your code here */});`

Comment: It is already inside $(document).ready(function(). Sorry I didn't mention that, but it's almost always the case that all jquery code is wrapped in that. So I thought it went without saying.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    allowProductChangeToRun = true;
});
```

allowProductChangeToRun doesn't get set to true until after all jquery stuff runs during initial page load. Apparently this is absolutely the last js to run, which is perfect.

Comment: Hi, Do you wrap this outside the "$(document).on('change') function ? or where should i put this. thanks