# How can I automatically save in django-admin editable listviews (or popup a reminder) on leave

Tags: python, django, listview, django-views, django-1.11

### Problem

I have a question on **how to save in editable listviews in the django-admin**. I use django 1.11 with python 3.6.

Suppose I have a **list of 100-200 Events** in a model. In order to **bulk edit** a boolean field for all entries, I register the model in **admin-view** as editable list (see code below).

For convenience, I slice the task and display 30 entries per page by using the pagination. **If I switch to the next page without pressing the save button, the changes will be lost.**

Now: how can I prevent loss of my input? Is there a django method to save automatically? I can imagine three ways, but I don't know how to implement it in django.

1. Instant save for the respective entry, when its checkbox is checked.
2. Hook on the pagination buttons: When I press any page number, the
   changes are saved.
3. A Popup with warning or save button, when I leave
   the page without having saved.

Has anybody a suggestion or code snippets for any of the three ways? Or a suggestion for different approach?

Thank you!

### Minimal Example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    relevant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s'  % (self.name, description)


class Event_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'relevant')
    list_editable = ('relevant')

    list_per_page = 30

admin.site.register(Event, Event_Admin)
```

Comment: You need some javascript to pick it up and save to the db. I'd go with option 1, instant save to db. You could write your own script and send an AJAX request. Or maybe look at grapelli or django-admin-tools, not sure if they do what you want.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I just extended my admin to do exactly that. I've been using Django for a very long time and did not know about `list_editable` - making it save in real time was the first thing I looked into, which led me to your question! :-)

---

- you will need to override the `change_list.html` admin template for this. create `(app name)/templates/admin/(app name)/change_list.html` and make sure that it overrides the admin's page (you might need to adjust the order of your `INSTALLED_APPS` and/or edit `TEMPLATES[0].DIRS`) -- see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories) for more info.
- once your own `change_list.html` overrides the admin's one, paste the following into it:

```html
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
  {{ block.super }}

  <script>
    const $ = django.jQuery;

    // we need to monitor $(window).ready,
    // as all of the <inputs> get an initial (spurious-ish) 'change'
    // event that we want to ignore.
    // once the window has fully loaded, we'll know that the change
    // events are 'real' i.e. they come from the user.
    // this comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20788889
    let windowHasLoaded = false;
    $(window).ready(function() {
      windowHasLoaded = true;
    })

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      const $form = $("form#changelist-form");
      // whenever any of the field values in the form change,
      // start a timeout; if another change happens during that period,
      // cancel and restart the timeout.
      // when the timeout expires, submit the form in the background.
      let timeout = null;

      $form.on("change", "input, select, textarea", function(event) {
        if(!windowHasLoaded) {
          return;
        }

        if (timeout) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
        }

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          // submit the form in the background using ajax
          // by simulating a click on the submit button

          // find the submit button
          const $saveButton = $form.find("input[type=submit]");
          // get the form as an array
          let serializedFormArray = $form.serializeArray();
          // set the action to the save button's name/value
          serializedFormArray.push({
            name: $saveButton.attr("name"),
            value: $saveButton.attr("value")
          });
          // convert the array to a query string
          const serializedForm = $.param(serializedFormArray);

          $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: serializedForm,
            success: function() {
            },
            error: function() {
              alert("Form auto save did not work!");
            }
          });
        }, 500);
      });
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```